# git clone hangs at "checking connectivity"

Tags: windows, git, github

OS - Windows 7 professional 64 bit

GIT for windows - Git-1.9.0 - Using Git bash

I started having problems with "git fetch" suddenly out of nowhere.

Sometimes git.exe would error out and sometimes the "git fetch" would just hang.

So I decided to start everything from scratch.

I uninstalled git for windows and reinstalled it (accepting all defaults), restarted the machine.  Created a brand new folder and did the following

```
$ git clone git@github.com:myid@example.com/myproject.git
Cloning into 'myproject'...
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/myid/.ssh/id_rsa':
remote: Counting objects: 287209, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (86467/86467), done.
remote: Total 287209 (delta 188451), reused 287209 (delta 188451)
Receiving objects: 100% (287209/287209), 168.89 MiB | 328.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (188451/188451), done.
Checking connectivity...
```

It consistently just hangs at "checking connectivity"

I have scanned the machine for viruses/trojans what have you and no threats were found.

This is happening both at work location and from home - So its probably not the internet.

I'm not sure how to proceed or what to try next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the `known_hosts` file from my `~/.ssh` folder, which did the trick.  Everything works now.

Comment: Where is this folder located?

Comment: It is probably not a great idea to delete your .ssh folder. It holds all of your ssh keys and configuration.

Answer (score 4):

This message is not related to network connectivity. This is about checking whether every object is connected to an existing reference.

Detailed answer can be found on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1054282/git-clone-checking-connectivity-what-is-it)

Comment: ^ Jonas is correct. "Connectivity" here means *graph* connectivity, since in git all commits are, are nodes in a generic N-ary tree graph. Nodes not connected to anything are called "orphan" commits, which `git gc` can safely clean up after.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run git with setting environment variable `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` to see what is going on.

Comment: Now I get this "Checking connectivity... fatal: remote did not send all necessary objects" and next line "Unlink of file 'myproject/.git/objects/pack/pack-ce829859ab3615e4cbcb421746d0a59b305a6ac8.idx' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)"

Answer (score 0):

This should improve with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), where the code that handles large number of refs in the "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/deec8aa2d05aba0a2ba495f9d41ab4e2805c8b9e/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> code path has been optimazed.

See [commit caff8b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/caff8b73402d4b5edb2c6c755506c5a90351b69a), [commit 1c7d1ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c7d1ab6f4a79e44406f304ec01b0a143dae9abb), [commit 284b2ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/284b2ce8fcb100e7194b9cca6d9b99bca7da39b6), [commit 62b5a35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62b5a35a33ad6a4537e2ae75a49036e4173fcc87), [commit 9fec7b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9fec7b213045135655354e864d15894175428d5a), [commit 47c6100](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47c61004c7cfbb8662b13fac813b45e3fd214665), [commit fe7df03](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe7df03a9a2fa434ebce38b2cd5e6da42f8b2692) (01 Sep 2021) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit deec8aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/deec8aa2d05aba0a2ba495f9d41ab4e2805c8b9e), 20 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/caff8b73402d4b5edb2c6c755506c5a90351b69a): avoid second connectivity check if we already have all objects
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> When fetching refs, we are doing two connectivity checks:
>
> - The first one is done such that we can skip fetching refs in the case where we already have all objects referenced by the updated set of refs.
> - The second one verifies that we have all objects after we have fetched objects.
>
> We always execute both connectivity checks, but this is wasteful in case the first connectivity check already notices that we have all objects locally available.
>
> **Skip the second connectivity check in case we already had all objects available**.
> This gives us a nice speedup when doing a mirror-fetch in a repository with about 2.3M refs where the fetching repo already has all objects:
>
> ```
> Benchmark #1: HEAD~: git-fetch
>   Time (mean ± σ):     30.025 s ±  0.081 s    [User: 27.070 s, System: 4.933 s]
>   Range (min … max):   29.900 s … 30.111 s    5 runs
>
> Benchmark #2: HEAD: git-fetch
>   Time (mean ± σ):     25.574 s ±  0.177 s    [User: 22.855 s, System: 4.683 s]
>   Range (min … max):   25.399 s … 25.765 s    5 runs
>
> Summary
>   'HEAD: git-fetch' ran
>     1.17 ± 0.01 times faster than 'HEAD~: git-fetch'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [fetch optimization of Git 2.34](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69428197/6309), you now have, with Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), a new "`fetch.hideRefs`" option can be used to exclude specified refs from "[`rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4d87411ffe2432efa8800b9e9d889241dd0f1f07/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L889)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---objects))</sup> traversal for checking object connectivity, most useful when there are many unrelated histories in a single repository.

See [commit c6ce27a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6ce27ab08d30dd9d626d7a56cb928bc5792eb27) (12 Feb 2023) by [Eric Wong (`ele828`)](https://github.com/ele828).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4d87411](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d87411ffe2432efa8800b9e9d889241dd0f1f07), 17 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6ce27ab08d30dd9d626d7a56cb928bc5792eb27): support `hideRefs` to speed up connectivity checks
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Wong</sup>

> With roughly 800 remotes all fetching into their own `refs/remotes/$REMOTE/*` island, the connectivity check[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69428197/6309) gets expensive for each fetch on systems which lack sufficient RAM to cache objects.
>
> To do a no-op fetch on one `$REMOTE` out of hundreds, `hideRefs` now allows the no-op fetch to take ~30 seconds instead of ~20 minutes on a noisy, RAM-constrained machine (localhost, so no network latency):
>
> ```
> git -c fetch.hideRefs=refs \
>     -c fetch.hideRefs='!refs/remotes/$REMOTE/' \
>  fetch $REMOTE
> ```
>
> [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69428197/6309) [`git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c6ce27ab08d30dd9d626d7a56cb928bc5792eb27/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L889)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---objects))</sup>

`git rev-parse` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c6ce27ab08d30dd9d626d7a56cb928bc5792eb27/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt#L200-L204):

> ### `--exclude-hidden=[fetch|receive|uploadpack]`
>
> Do not include refs that would be hidden by `git-fetch`,
> `git-receive-pack` or `git-upload-pack` by consulting the appropriate
> `fetch.hideRefs`, `receive.hideRefs` or `uploadpack.hideRefs`
> configuration along with `transfer.hideRefs`

`rev-list-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c6ce27ab08d30dd9d626d7a56cb928bc5792eb27/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L198-L202) a similar option.

Answer (score -1):

You should execute "git prune".

Comment: It would be helpful to indicate why this would help

Comment: I agree that it would be helpful, but for the moment I just know that it works.